# Access to folders goes away when restarting the app

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox

My app needs access to certain folders and the contents of them (that the user picks) outside of the sandbox.  I have that working well and all, however when the app restarts, I can still see what’s inside the folder, but I can’t read the files inside the folder.

I’m getting access to the folder through a simple `NSOpenPanel`, which like I said, works and gives me access to all files and subfolders until the app is restarted.

Is there any way I can make it so the NSOpenPanel grants me permanent access to the files?

Comment: You need a [Security Scoped Bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep/bookmark/enabling_security-scoped_bookmark_and_url_access)

Answer (score 0):

The permission has been revert back to its original condition when restarted , you might want to check again the implementation of the folder access to be granted automatically

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try to save the urls bookmark data instead of just a path as you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox/accessing_files_from_the_macos_app_sandbox).